# Tweepy Transform list of tweets(json) into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, tweepy

I am trying to get a data frame over the below list of tweets. However, none of the solutions online do help.

1. When I try to save the searched results on a json file I get

   > 'dict' object has no attribute '_json

def write_tweets(tweets, filename):
    ''' Function that appends tweets to a file. '''

using the below code:

```
def write_tweets(tweets, filename):
''' Function that appends tweets to a file. '''

with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    for tweet in tweets:
        json.dump(tweet._json, f)
        f.write('\n')                               
write_tweets(searched_tweets,"data.json")
```

2. trying to transform my results to a dataframe also fails:

   DataSet['tweetID'] = [tweet.id for tweet in searched_tweets]

My full code is the below and returns the researched_results which is a list.

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import json

df= pd.read_excel(dataNLP.xlsx")

IDs = df["TweetID"].tolist()

def load_api():
    ''' Function that loads the twitter API after authorizing
        the user. '''
   # ApI Keys
    consumer_key = "--"
    consumer_secret = "--"
    access_token = "-----"
    access_token_secret = "-"
    #Pass our consumer key and consumer secret to Tweepy's user authentication handler
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    #Pass our access token and access secret to Tweepy's user authentication handler
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    # load the twitter API via tweepy
    return tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True,parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser())

#Connect
api = load_api()

#Creating a twitter API wrapper using tweepy
i = 0
#jump 188 as per tweeter api
step = 100
searched_tweets=[]
cant_find_tweets_for_those_ids = []
cant_find_tweets_for_those_ids_whole =[]
while i <= len(IDs):
    for each_id in IDs[i:(i+step)]:
        try:
            new_tweets =   api.api.statuses_lookup(IDs[i:(i+step)])
            print( "found", len(new_tweets),"tweets")
            searched_tweets.extend(new_tweets)
            print( "added", len(searched_tweets),"in searched_tweets")
            i= i + step +1
        except Exception as e:
            cant_find_tweets_for_those_ids.append(each_id)
            cant_find_tweets_for_those_ids_whole.extend(cant_find_tweets_for_those_ids)
```

Example IDs :597576902212063232, 565586175864610817.

Expected dataframe result could be something with the following fields:
ID, text, user_location, hastags, followers count, friends count, re tweet count.
Could someone explain what I am doing wrong or how I can get a workable daframe from the searched_tweets list with json objects?

An element of the searched_tweets list:

```
{'truncated': False, 'in_reply_to_user_id': 297535251, 'place': None, 'retweet_count': 0, 'created_at': 'Mon Feb 23 20:28:36 +0000 2015', 'in_reply_to_screen_name': 'OutworldDOTA2', 'source': '<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>', 'favorited': False, 'contributors': None, 'is_quote_status': False, 'geo': None, 'id': 569957017655226369, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str': '569956825057120256', 'in_reply_to_status_id': 569956825057120256, 'coordinates': None, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str': '297535251', 'id_str': '569957017655226369', 'lang': 'en', 'user': {'description': 'Founder, Online Abuse Prevention Initiative. v (gaming account: @grandma_kj)', 'default_profile': False, 'profile_sidebar_border_color': '181A1E', 'name': 'needlessly obscenity-laced', 'time_zone': 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)', 'profile_banner_url': 'link', 'screen_name': 'randileeharper', 'favourites_count': 66157, 'translator_type': 'regular', 'contributors_enabled': False, 'created_at': 'Sat Feb 23 07:27:19 +0000 2008', 'protected': False, 'notifications': False, 'profile_background_color': '1A1B1F', 'following': False, 'id_str': '13857342', 'location': 'Portland, OR', 'entities': {'description': {'urls': [{'url': 'link, 'expanded_url': 'link', 'indices': [45, 68], 'display_url': 'patreon.com/freebsdgirl'}]}, 'url': {'urls': [{'url': 'link': 'link', 'indices': [0, 23], 'display_url': 'blog.randi.io'}]}}, 'id': 13857342, 'utc_offset': -28800, 'has_extended_profile': True, 'profile_sidebar_fill_color': '252429', 'profile_image_url': 'link', 'friends_count': 787, 'verified': True, 'link': 'link', 'profile_background_image_url': 'link', 'profile_link_color': '2FC2EF', 'profile_text_color': '666666', 'is_translator': False, 'lang': 'en', 'geo_enabled': True, 'statuses_count': 123525, 'profile_image_url_link', 'default_profile_image': False, 'url': 'link', 'listed_count': 901, 'followers_count': 20638, 'follow_request_sent': False, 'profile_use_background_image': True, 'profile_background_tile': False, 'is_translation_enabled': False}, 'text': '@OutworldDOTA2 i\'m very entertained that all it takes is "155 IQ" for me to know precisely who is being discussed.', 'retweeted': False, 'entities': {'hashtags': [], 'urls': [], 'symbols': [], 'user_mentions': [{'id_str': '297535251', 'screen_name': 'OutworldDOTA2', 'name': 'Follow Your Leader', 'indices': [0, 14], 'id': 297535251}]}, 'favorite_count': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time. Both solutions give the same error. 'list' object has no attribute '_json'.  Searched_tweets is a list of tweets. i want to be able to save it as a json format and then transform it to a dataframe. the only that seems to work isfrom pandas.io.json import

```
json_normalize
data_nested = json_normalize(searched_tweets)
data = data_nested[["entities.hashtags","favorite_count","id","id_str","lang","retweet_count","retweeted","text","user.description","user.entities.description.urls","user.favourites_count","user.follow_request_sent","user.followers_count","user.following","user.friends_count","user.geo_enabled","user.has_extended_profile","user.id","user.id_str","user.is_translation_enabled","user.is_translator","user.lang","user.listed_count","user.location","user.name","user.notifications","user.translator_type","user.verified"]].copy()
```

I am not sure thogh how I can trasform it and save it as a json file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    json.dump(tweet._json, f)
```

tweet._json returns a dictionary. Hence the error message. Personally, that's the way I prefer to do it.

If you just want a list of tweets then declare a list and add each tweet dictionary to it.

```
tweet_list = []
for tweet in tweets:
    tweet_list.append(tweet._json)
```

You can then access the tweet attributes by list index, and dictionary key.

```
print(tweet_list[0].get("text"))
print(tweet_list[0].get("created_at")
```

if you want to save the list to file you can use pickle.

```
import pickle

def pickle_data(filename, tweet_list):
    with open(filename, "wb") as handle:
        pickle.dump(tweet_list, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

and when you want to load the files, you can load it straight back into a list of dictionaries.

```
def unpickle_data(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as handle:
        tweet_list = pickle.load(handle)
    return tweet_list
```

Not sure this was exactly what you were looking for but I hope you can use something.

Comment: Hi Neil,Thank you for taking the time. Both solutions give the same error. 'list' object has no attribute '_json'.  Searched_tweets is a list of tweets. i want to be able to save it as a json format and then transform it to a dataframe. the only that seems to work is